# %matplotlib qt real-time online plotting in Jupyter-Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I have been using Jupyter-Notebook for educational purposes, i.e., Integration between a computer networking emulator written in python and running the experiments in Jupyter-Notebook. To enhance graphical interaction, the network simulator, called mininet-wifi, has the following Plotting function, which is used to plot nodes location. i.e [class Plot2D (object).](https://github.com/intrig-unicamp/mininet-wifi/blob/master/mn_wifi/plot.py)
The problem is whenever the matplotlib is called using

```
%matplotlib qt
```

As the plot is opened in a new window, everything seems to be working properly with plotting. But, I want to draw the plotting embedded inside the cell. Using the

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Works in this case, but as depicted in the [illustration photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVf1M.png), only one frame of the plotting is drawn and the rest of the code is executed.

Is there any way to obtain the behavior of `%matplolib qt` inside the cell?

Comment: you might want `%matplotlib notebook`

Comment: @PaulH: Dear Paul, Unfortunately, It does not work in this case. It output's only a white blank figure.